# How to change only the first occurrence of an object in an ArrayList, ignoring subsequent duplicates, in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I wish to take an array of integers and check it against two numbers, the first of which is the number in the array that I want to replace and the second number is the number that I wish to replace the first number by. I have managed to write the code to do this both destructively and constructively, but I want to only change the first occurrence of the number I first enter to the second number, not all the entries.

For example, if I were to enter {3, 5, 1, 3, 6} and 3 as the number I wish to replace and 9 as the number I wanted to replace it by, I should get {9, 5, 1, 3, 6} since I only want to change the **first occurrence** of 3 to 9, not both.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ex6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter some numbers. When you're done, type 999");
        boolean cont = true;
        while (cont == true) {
            int x = scanner.nextInt();
            if (x == 999) {
                cont = false;
            } else {
                list.add(x);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Enter a number to replace");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberCompare = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the number you want to replace it with");
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberReplace = sc2.nextInt();
        changeD(list, numberCompare, numberReplace);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
        //System.out.println(changeC(list, numberCompare, numberReplace));
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> changeD(ArrayList<Integer> list, int numberCompare, int numberReplace) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) == numberCompare) {
                list.set(i, numberReplace);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

        /*I am only using one method at a time, depending on what I wish to 
    test. The above changes 
      destructively and below changes constructively*/

        /*public static ArrayList<Integer> changeC(ArrayList<Integer> list, int 
    numberCompare, int numberReplace) {
            ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                int x = list.get(i);
                b.add(x);
            }
            for(int j = 0; j<b.size(); j++) {
                if(b.get(j) == numberCompare) {
                    b.set(j, numberReplace);
                }
            }
            return b;
        }*/
}
```

I am also curious about the code in the main method that adds the user input into the ArrayList. Is there a better way, that doesn't require the user to enter `999` in order to break out of the `while` loop.

Comment: Add a `break;` after the call to `list.set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a break statement inside your if:

```
if (list.get(i) == numberCompare) {
    list.set(i, numberReplace);
    break;
}
```

That way the loop will be interrupted the first time the condition is true.

Answer (score 2):

So, don't change next values of the `List`.
Actually you iterate on every elements.
You should stop as soon as you set a value.

Besides, the method should return nothing.
You return the object passed as parameter. It is not required and you don't use it in the client side either.
At last, program by interface. Prefer `List` over `ArrayList` as declared type.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
...
public static void changeD(List<Integer> list, int 
numberCompare, int numberReplace) {
    for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        if(list.get(i) == numberCompare) {
            list.set(i, numberReplace);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```